# CSS text overflow in responsive design using Viewport units

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am experiencing problems trying to incorporate overflow truncating into my "responsive" website design using viewport units to resize divs and text according to viewport size.
I have tried using overflow, text-overflow and jquery.dotdotdot to no avail. I couldn't get SO's code blocks to play so I've pasted on pastebin.

HTML ([PasteBin link](http://pastebin.com/RTejGhV3))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

    <title>OBS NP</title>
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <link href="apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">-->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bg"></div>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
           <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
       <![endif]-->

        <div class="header-container">
            <header class="wrapper">
                <h1 class="title">Now Playing</h1>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="main">
                <span class="AlbumArt"><img alt="Album Art" src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/9544097.jpg"></span>


                <header class="SongTitle">
                    <h1>Republic of Dreams</h1>

                    <p>There's No Bullshitting Here</p>
                </header>
            </div><!-- #main -->
        </div><!-- #main-container -->

        <div class="footer-container">
            <footer class="wrapper">
                <h3>OBS Now Playing, by <a href=
               "https://twitter.com/nicholainissen">@nicholainissen</a></h3>
            </footer>
        </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <script>
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.dotdotdot/1.7.2/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- chrome fonts for outdated shit? -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('head').append('<link href="css/chrome.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS ([PasteBin link](http://pastebin.com/9dqq9D5u))

```
/*@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin,greek-ext,latin-ext);*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,700,700italic,400italic&subset=latin,latin-ext);
/* ===== OBS NP CSS ==================================================

   Author: Nicholai Nissen, using
   HTML5 Boilerplate v5.0 | MIT License | http://h5bp.com/

   Warning: 'Expletives might occur, browse this source at your own peril';

   ========================================================================== */

/* ==============================
   Absolutely clean slate
   Ultra Mega Css Reset h4x 666!!
   ============================== */
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,caption {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent
}

/* ============================================================================== */

html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    font-size:1vmin;
    color:#FEFEFE;
    line-height:1.4
}

body {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);    /*
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 -1px, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0 0 10px, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0 50px;*/
}

img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:50vh;
    width:50vh
}

* {
    box-sizing:border-box
}

.bg {
    background-image: url('http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/174s/68195184.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    -webkit-filter:blur(15px);
    -moz-filter:blur(15px);
    -o-filter:blur(15px);
    -ms-filter:blur(15px);
    filter:blur(15px);
    height:800px;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    z-index:0;
}

.content {
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    top:10px;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    right:0;
    z-index:2;
    padding:0 10px
}

.browserupgrade {
    margin:.2em 0;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#000;
    padding:.2em 0
}

.wrapper {
    width:100vw;
    margin:0 1%
}

/* ===================
    Fuck this theme
   =================== */

.header-container {
    position:absolute;
    color:#fff;
    height:25vh;
    z-index:3;
}

.footer-container {
    position:fixed;
    color:#fff;
    top:85vh;
    height:15vh;
    z-index:3;
}

.main-container {
    top:25vh;
    height:60vh;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    max-height:60vh;
}

a,a:link,a:visited,a:active,a:hover {
    color:#fff
}

.title {
}

header h1 {
    font-size:23vmin;
    font-weight:700;
    z-index:3;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 18px rgba(0, 0, 15, 0.53);
    text-overflow:ellipsis
}

header p {
    font-size:20vmin;
    font-weight:400;
    z-index:3;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 18px rgba(0, 0, 15, 0.53);
    text-overflow:ellipsis
}

footer h3 {
    float:right;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:8vmin;
    padding-right:5vh;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
}

.SongTitle {
    float:right;
    width:100vw-50vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.AlbumArt {
    float:left;
    padding:5vh
}

.main{
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

This is my first time around using viewport units, i've had limited success with css based ellipsing before, but this just drives me nuts.

Comment: I don't see any media queries in your CSS. How are you implementing responsiveness?

Comment: What does "problems"  mean? Please be specific.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help, especially [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) chapter and try to improve your post.

Comment: Halcyon: Using viewport units.  
  
@Paulie_D: Sorry for not clarifying. The text in .SongTitle does not clip, gets hidden or ellipsed. The h1 and p elements simply move down under the image, where I instead want them to say in their place and any overflow handled by ellipsing.  
  
Akarienta: Pardon me.

Comment: text-overflow comes avalaible if content text stands on 1 line and if overflow is set to hidden, Can you set a fiddle or a codepen so you show us live your trouble :)

Comment: @GCyrillus: Content does indeed stand on a single line.
http://jsfiddle.net/5aqphfor/
Here you go.  
Try resizing the viewport.

Comment: white-space (to force 1 line) + overflow:hidden and it works fine : http://jsfiddle.net/5aqphfor/1/

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the text needs to stand on one line and `overflow` needs to be set to `hidden` in order to trigger `ellipsis` effect.

update this part of CSS

```
header h1 {
font-size:23vmin;
font-weight:700;
z-index:3;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 18px rgba(0, 0, 15, 0.53);
text-overflow:ellipsis;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5aqphfor/1/

If `white-space` is not set to `nowrap`, text will wrap/break in more than 1 line :)

Comment: But if you try it out, it only works on the uppermost h1, the other h1 and the p (the ones I care about) still breaks down to the next line before overflowing. (I tried applying the code to the p as well)

Comment: @NicholaiNissen ?? what matters is the way to apply this, use the selector that you need, h1, p, whatever ... overflow:hidden + white-space:nowrap and text-overflow:ellipsis are the 3 rules to put together . none more or less

Comment: As stated; I did this. It does not work, regardless of how many times you tell me it should. Look at the fiddle. It only works on the first h1, not any other text object.